# Site wide invalid Imagepaths withe Amazon S3 and IMCE

Tags: 7, files

I'm working on an already existing page to make some updates. In the process Drupal 7 changed the images paths in the nodes, resulting into wrong paths to images.

The only thing I did that would explain this behavior was an update to the Amazon S3 module, to be able to use IMCE again.

A correct path would be:
amazonaws.com/projectfolder/subfolder/image.png

The wrong path that is used now is:
amazonaws.com/subfolder/image.png

This is a problem on the whole site. I can be certain that the URL on the S3 didn't change. What I think I would need to do is to add the "/projectfolder" folder to the url.

I can't think about a tool or way to do that.

I would appreciate some help, or insight.

Thank you!